# FMDB / sqlite query problem with function

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

I am really new to swift and trying to understand ios programming. Basically I have a table where "id" and "fact" columns. id is primary key'd  and here is the swift fuction I am trying to query the values

```
func getItemsFromRow(fact_cid: String) ->[FactsData]{
    var rowData: [FactsData]!
    let rawQ = "select * from facts where \(facts_id)=?"
    if (openDatabase()){
        do{
            let results = try database.executeQuery(rawQ, value(forKey: fact_cid))
            while results.next(){
                let currentFact = FactsData(factid: results.string(forColumn: facts_id), factsdata: results.string(forColumn: facts_fld))
                if rowData == nil {
                    rowData = [FactsData]()
                }
                rowData.append(currentFact)
            }
        }
    }
    return rowData
}
```

But this line gives me error

```
let results = try database.executeQuery(rawQ, value(forKey: fact_cid))
```

Error is

```
Cannot invoke 'executeQuery' with an argument list of type '(String, Any?)'
```

I am trying to pass the id as string. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
let results = try database.executeQuery(rawQ, values: [fact_cid])
```

since the second parameter should be an array

Comment: Sorry actually now I am getting this error. Use of 'value' nearly matches class method 'value(forKey:)' in class 'NSObject' rather than instance method 'value(forKey:)'

Comment: @Achayan how, there is no “value” in my answer?

Comment: sorry I think it was mistake from my side and it is working sorry about that and thanks for the help